# How to create parallel testing with suites, but depend on variable or group

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I use Selenium WebDriver, Java, TestNG, Maven and Surefire to launch automation tests.
I have many tests, but they are operates on 2 independent groups of users. One group I use to check privileges and second group for other operations. I would like to create parallel tests, but not adding any new test to suiteXmlFiles.

Currently, I in tensng.xml I defined only package:

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="BrainshareItSuite">
<test name="AllTests" >
    <packages>
        <package name="com.brainshare.faktury.qa.*"/>
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

and it works fine, because all new test form package are added automatically to my suite. I would save this automation adding new tests.

Can I create 2 parallel groups of test, which will be depending on variables, e.g logins of users.
Alternately, I can adding group, eg.'privileges' to @Test annotation. Then launch groups: 1st - with 'privileges', 2nd -without 'privileges' in parallel? But where   can I add this?

Comment: The question is still not clear. Can you please provide some examples of what you are trying to do, when you say `create 2 parallel groups of test` ?

Comment: Of course, it should be "tests" not "test".

Answer (score 1):

Phew! Lots of questions! Where do we start? :)

From your title I think you are trying to solve too many problems at once. The part that's not very clear is the:

> depend on variable or group

To my knowledge you cannot run suites in parallel using an xml file.
However you can via the cmd, quoting from testNG doc:

```
5.10.1 - Parallel suites
This is useful if you are running several suite files (e.g. "java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml testng2.xml") and you want each of these suites to be run in a separate thread. You can use the following command line flag to specify the size of a thread pool:
java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 3 testng1.xml testng2.xml testng3.xml
```

In your example above, you have thread-count=1 but I am not sure this can be applied on suite level from the xml. Again quoting from testNG doc:
5.10.2 - Parallel tests, classes and methods

```
The parallel attribute on the <suite> tag can take one of following values:
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
```

Finally, another possible solution using Maven is to:
a) Use `forkCount` in your surefire plugin to define number of threads, so 2 in your case and you also want to `reuseForks` (meaning when a thread becomes available begin a new test).
b) Make sure you specify both suite names under config as well

Launch as `mvn test`

```
<plugins>                    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.20.1</version>

  <configuration>

        <forkCount>2</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>

        <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>BrainshareItSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFile>NotAprivilegedBunchSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>

   </configuration>

        <goals>
         <goal>integration-test</goal>
       </goals>  

  </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

However, I don't think the above is very efficient (because in essence you have only 2 threads executing scripts. Personally, I will try to solve this differently but maybe that's me.

In addition you also mention groups (yes you can define them at the top of your test class so you don't need to define each group in every single method) and then yes again you can run separate groups in parallel but this has to be `parallel="tests"` on this occasion.

But why groups? Why not having a single xml with all the tests inside executing, at the same time? After all a `suite` is just a `collection of test classes` and you don't seem to have a need to halt one suite until the other one executes. So, something like this will be me:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression" parallel="tests" thread-count="15">


 <parameter name="env" value="stage" />   
 <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/> 



 <test name="login1">   
    <classes>   
    <class name="regression.login.emailLogin"/> 
        </classes>
    </test>   


 <test name="login2">   
    <classes>   
    <class name="regression.login.fbLogin"/>    
        </classes>
    </test>



<test name="login3">    
    <classes>   
    <class name="regression.login.forgottenPassLink"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

  [..]

 </suite>
```

In the above example, hopefully I will help with your question regarding `depending on variable`. You can pass the params from xml and then having an if clause perhaps at the start of your test so you can direct the flow from there. I will stick it in a before class for example so I load my envrinoment and choose a form of the webdriver, but you can do whatever you want from there:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"browser", "env"})
public void initialSetup(String browser, String env){       

    login.setup(browser, env);
}
```

As a final note, I better let you know that you can also use `data providers` to load all users to one test.  Maybe this is what you are after all:

```
5.6.2 - Parameters with DataProviders

Specifying parameters in testng.xml might not be sufficient if you need to pass complex parameters, or parameters that need to be created from Java (complex objects, objects read from a property file or a database, etc...). In this case, you can use a Data Provider to supply the values you need to test.  A Data Provider is a method on your class that returns an array of array of objects.  This method is annotated with @DataProvider:

//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
will print

Cedric 36
Anne 37
```

Hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Xwris Stoixeia for advices, there are lots of them. I'll try to use it to make my tests shorter.

Comment: Np glad if I can be of some help. If you have a lots of accounts you probably need to look at the data provider as it can run the same test, multiple times with different credentials. But it might make things tricky when executing in parallel. Generally parallelism is hard to achieve as you will have scripts clashing with each other, until you get it right.

Nevertheless, I still believe that if you are after execution time, you can setup selenium grid hub, throw all java classes in a XML and then watch them execute at batches of 10 :) Also have a look at Headless Chromedriver  ;)

Comment: Headless chrome is very simple and yes it still takes screenshot. Get the latest chromedriver and then just use this line below to run your suite headless:

Comment: options.addArguments("--headless")  ;options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

Comment: If you still need to stick with your original idea (run 2 suites in paralllel) --> follow the instructions for maven and this should be the easier out of everything we discussed! Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for another advice. I am creating test for webpages, which were created in JSF, and whan I use --headless argument, WebDriver can't find elements. For Instance: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id$=login]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120

Comment: So I imagine, when you don't use  headless it locates correctly. I can see you use CSS. Have you tried xpath instead? So in your example above this would be the xpath locator (or almost, you need to check the element's tag, is it a div, span, li..

Comment: //div[@id='login']

Comment: Thanks for new solutions, but the reason of failure is in code of webpage https://saldeo.brainshare.pl created in technology JSF. When I use example from https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/running-selenium-tests-with-chrome-headless-5edd624efb92 everything works fine. :)

Comment: That's weird! I just tried it and Chromedriver can find your login button with xpath but not when using headless! You should report it to google as a bug so they fix it in their next chromedriver version :)